# complexity of CSPs with 2-variable constraints and multi-valued variables

Tags: np-hardness

(CSP = "constraint satisfaction problem")

CSPs for which either the variables are restricted to less than two values or the constraints

take less than two inputs are obviously trivial, and [Schaefer's dichotomy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem)

gives the complete situation for variables with two possible values.

How hard is it to solve CSPs with 2-variable constraints

but variables that can take more than two values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With 3 values and binary relations, the CSP is still NP-complete (it is denoted with (3,2)-CSP). A quick reduction is from graph coloring:

add a variable $x_i \in \{1,2,3\}$ for each node; then for each edge $(x_i,x_j)$ add the constraint $x_i \neq x_j$

Answer (score 2):

[Schöning's algorithm](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~davet/ubcsat/algorithms/Schoening99.pdf) runs in time $O\left(\left(\frac{d(k-1)}{k}\right)^n\right)$, where $k$ is the clause width and $d$ is the number of possible values per variable.

Comment: For (3,2)-CSP I think that the current best is $O(1.3645^n)$ (n is the number of variables) by [Richard Beigel and David Eppstein](http://arxiv.org/abs/cs.DS/0006046)